# @OneToOne without saving child information

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

here is my problem. 
I've two clases defined like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CAR")
public class Car{

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        @Column(name = "CAR_ID", nullable = false)
        private Long idCar;

        @NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
        @JoinColumn(name="BRAND")
        @OneToOne(targetEntity = Brand.class, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade=CascadeType.DETACH)
        private Brand idBrand;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "BRAND")
public class Brand{

       @Id
       @Column(name = "BRAND_ID")
       private Long idBrand;

       @Column(name = "DESCRIPTION")
       private String description;

}
```

I need to save a Car without saving brand information. If I try to save as it is now, I have a Database error: Field 'BRAND_ID' doesn't have a default value 
It seems that its trying to save in BRAND database, but I only need to save the column BRAND in Car object.

In the other hand, if I made a get of a Car, with a brand saved, I recover it properly.

EDIT:
What I'm trying is to save a car Object with JPA repository. This Car is filled with a Brand object, that only has a brand ID.

```
Car myCar = new Car();
Brand myBrand = new Brand();
myBrand.setIdBrand(11l);
myCar.setIdBrand(myBrand);
repository.save(myCar);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried the `OneToOne.optional` attribute?

Comment: Yes, I tried with this combination, but didn't work either: @ManyToOne(targetEntity = PageInfo.class, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade=CascadeType.DETACH, optional=true)

Comment: "I have a table filled with lots of brands and its an optional value for the Car, I dont need to insert more values in BRANDS". Then load a brand, associate it with a car, and save the car. Your question does not show the code, where you are trying to _save_ any data.

Comment: What I was trying is to save a Car object, with a JPA repository. repository.save(myCar), wich will have a Brand object, with the idBrand filled.

Comment: Hi @ThomasTimbul, with optional attribute worked! I misswrited it earlier, sorry about that and thanks for your comment!

Answer (score -1):

You need to make the "BRAND_ID" column nullable in the database, apparently the column is currently "not null".

Not sure if the table was generated using hibernate.

Comment: An primare key can not be _nullable_. Additionally, OP asked how to not save a brand in the table `BRAND`, but only in the table `CAR` (which is a bit unclear to me).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the tables weren't generated by hiberante. BRAND_ID column is the PRIMARY KEY in BRAND table. I put it nullable, with default value NULL, but its still giving me the same error.

Comment: Primary key cannot be nullable, but the foreign key can be nulable.

Comment: Hi @Seelenvirtuose, the thing is that I have a table filled with lots of brands and its an optional value for the Car, I dont need to insert more values in BRANDS